# What are Storage Engines in Relational databases?

Tags: relational-database, storage-engines

Can anybody tell me what are the storage engines with respect to relational databases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they are the part that actually stores data on the discs. That simple.

Comment: They are not categorized - those are DIFFERENT STORAGE ENGINES that MySQL can use. Same like a VOlkswagen and a Mercedes are different cars - not " cars categorized by mercedes and volkswagen".

Comment: You could categorize them as "able to support RDBMS integrity" and "not able to support RDBMS integrity" (MyISAM) and "somewhere in-between" (InnoDB)...